# Whatever happened to my buttons when i switch to mobile view?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Due to time issues, I downloaded a template called [Horizons](https://templated.co/horizons) by [Templated](http://templated.co) in order to use the CSS.

This CSS uses Javascript to initialize mobile view which makes the buttons go from inline to block.

At first it was all sunshine and rainbows but suddenly this happened to my buttons:

[Basically they go out of the div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd46f.png)
[Like so. (outlines of div and button)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nuuS.png)
I don't know what to do. Since its not like adding an @media and screens command.

I do have a

```
mobile:{ 
  range: '-640', 
  href: 'css/style-mobile.css', 
  containers: '90%',

  grid: { 
    gutters: 15, 
    collapse: 2 
  } 
}
```

and a

```
body, input, select, textarea {
    font-size: 11pt;
}

.button {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    line-height: 2.75em;
    height: 2.75em;
    margin: 1.5em


}
```

inside the style-mobile.css.

In my regular style.css I have:

```
input[type="submit"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="button"],
.button {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -o-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
    background: #4368b1;
    border-radius: 40px;
    border: 0;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.80em 2em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    font-weight: 600;
    min-width: 9em;
}
```

Don't know if this affects, but I am running my index as:

```
<?php
require "header.php";
```

and the rest of my body inside the page I'm having trouble with.

I'm not sure on what to do. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This may temporarily ruin your formatting, but set `margin: 1.5em` to `margin: 0` and see if you notice the same thing happening?

Comment: I tried it and it didn't actually change anything in the page. The buttons are still slightly to the right, outside of the div.

Comment: Are you able to post the code for the buttons / div / etc?

Comment: Sure. It goes on for about 5 more of this, having 6 buttons in total. 

`<div class="row no-collapse-1">
                <section class="4u">
                    <a href="#" class="button">Admin List</a>
                    <h4><br>Don't know what to put</h4>
                    <p style="position: relative; bottom: 0.8em">and offline staff, asswell as their roll.
                    <br>and use 2.
                    </p>                    
                </section>`

Comment: My recommendation is to turn on f12 developer tools in Chrome, and slowly disable pieces of your css from both the button & surrounding div. When you find out what nasty is causing the error, then you can fix it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im pretty new in html css php too but i think the reason why your buttons are acting like that is because of this

**min-width: 9em;**  -- > min-width 70%;

im not that familiar with em, but i rather use % than em then add padding if needed.

and also i would rather use bootstrap or materialize.css for than horizons to use the grid system more better. but this still depends on your own preference.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on bootstrap! Unfortunately, changing the min-width: 9em; -- > min-width 70%; didn't change the buttons.

The reason I'm using horizons's CSS is basically for laziness. And I have like 50+ pages already styled. So... Changing the style sheet will be a little complicated.

Comment: have you tried adding a container for the button then add this  in the css of the container                        
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

Comment: <div class="row no-collapse-1">
 <section class="4u">
 <div ="button-container">
    <a href="#" class="button">Admin List</a> 
  </div>
  <h4><br>Don't know what to put</h4>
      <p style="position: relative; bottom: 0.8em">
        and offline staff, asswell as their roll.
        <br>
        and use 2. 
      </p> 
  </section>

  .button-container{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
  }

Comment: Getting it inside a container helped moving it. Now, I have a skel.css with a lot of .containers in it. Do I replace them with the center content command you gave me?

Comment: if your skel.css is also displaying out of the div, then yes you should add center to it too. however if it is not, then you dont have to since based on my exp. i rarely touch the skel.css to center everything up.

Comment: you can also add max width or min width in your container and try to fidget around to find the right placement, but keep in mind to check the desktop web size, i also recommend using media queries if you dont have

Comment: How would I know if the skel.css is displaying outside the div?

Also, the problem with moving around the container is that I have the site so that on desktop, its shown one way. And on mobile its displayed another.

Comment: i used skel.css to act as a loader in infinite scrolling. just like in facebook when you scroll down and the content is not yet loaded

Comment: I found the solution by using the skel.css and finding out how the grid works. Basically had to try all the different rows available.

So, rather than having a class="container" I have a class="15u"

Comment: nicee Good job!.